# Weightlessness under freefall

Tags: forces, gravity, acceleration, free-fall, weight

What is 'weightlessness due to freefall '?

I asked this question to my teacher and he said that weightlessness experienced by a falling body when the acceleration of the body is equal to the acceleration due to gravity is called weightlessness under freefall.

Is this correct?  Or, are there any other definition.

Comment: do you have any particular reason to distrust your teacher? why are you unconvinced by his answer?

Comment: Did you ask him _why_ he said that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is *geodesic motion* i.e. a weightless observer is following [a trajectory called a geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity). However it is commonly known as free fall even amongst general relativists.

Any acceleration an observer feels, which is called [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), is the result of the observer deviating from a geodesic trajectory. This can be due to acceleration as in a fast car or gravitational acceleration as we feel when standing on the surface of the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

You feel that you have a weight when you feel the ground which you are standing on or a chair which you are sitting on pushes up on you.

In free fall although you still have the force of gravitational attraction on you due to the Earth but you **feel** weightless because there is nothing pushing up on you.

If you stood on some scales in a lift which was in free fall the reading on the scales would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is correct , but i like to think of weightlessness as what would a weighting machine show if you looked at it during freefall ( it measures normal force which comes to be zero in this case  ) as  u are acclerating you would have to apply pseudoforce which will be equal to  mg so normal would have to be zero as in your frame you would not be accelerating .